# What is the difference between /etc/rc.local and ~/.bashrc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This is a linux related problem. I have searched around but did not get a good explanation.

It seems to me that both file configure the setup when I log in, but is there any difference? I notice that there seems to be "some rule" in deciding what should go into two different files. For example, if I need to add a specific search path to $PATH, I should do it in ~/.bashrc. But if I decide to change some system setting, like

```
/sys/class/backlight
```

or

```
/sys/devices/cpu/cpu#/online
```

then I have to do this in /etc/rc.local, otherwise it will not work.

Is it because these configurations can not differ between users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is in when they are run and who they're running as when run i.e. rc.local is run on a change of run level and it runs as root. bashrc is bash specific and run on a non login shell as a particular user.

You can find a good explanation of `rc.local` here

> The script /etc/rc.local is for use by the system administrator. It is
>   traditionally executed after all the normal system services are
>   started, at the end of the process of switching to a multiuser
>   runlevel. You might use it to start a custom service, for example a
>   server that's installed in /usr/local. Most installations don't need
>   /etc/rc.local, it's provided for the minority of cases where it's
>   needed.

and you can find what you need about `bashrc`

```
man bash
```

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if  that
>   file exists. This  may be inhibited by using the --norc option.
>   The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and
>   execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

There's more info on bashrc in this question...

https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file

Answer (score 23):

This question was asked by me a month ago, though later I realized that stack overflow is not the best site for this Linux question. Thanks for people who answered this question earlier, but I would like to add some more explanation here.

Basically there are (at least) three stages where a user may change system environment in Linux:

1. **when the system boots**; This stage is most appropriate if we fancy **permanent system setting**, and should be made via `/etc/...`. For example, in my original question, the *backlight*, as well as *on-line/off-line management of some CPUs* can be set in this way, and `/etc/rc.local` is the right shell script I should edit. By "permanent", it means that this update will affect all users using the system.
2. **when a user logs in**; This stage is most appropriate if a user only wants to change his personal Linux environment. Therefore, files under `~/` (or `HOME`) should be the right place to look for. For example, `~/.profile` (historically referred to as `./bash_profile` or `~/bash_login`) is a shell script run at login time. `~/pam_environment` is **not** a shell script, but useful for setting environmental variables (see [Ubunte-official-wiki-environmental_variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) for more information).
3. **when a user starts a bash shell**; This stage is more restricted, as it only has effects inside a bash shell (as well as its child processes), hence does not affect GUI environment. So if a user is doing most of his job from a shell, then this is an appropriate stage to go for. The shell script related to this stage is `~/.bashrc`. For example, environmental variables `PATH` can be changed here.

Hopefully this summary is more intuitive than technical.

Answer (score 2):

`.bashrc` runs for each `bash` session started (i.e. every time you open a shell).  It sounds as though you're talking of `.bashrc` as if it were `.bash_profile` which is run once per login.

Depending on what kind of setup you're running the `rc.local` is a legacy construct but, traditionally it was run on the last run level during start up.  You can see this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/purpose-and-typical-usage-of-etc-rc-local) for other related posts talking about `rc.local`.

If you're on a system running `systemd` this is usually included by default in the `systemd` package [`systemd-backlight.service`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#systemd-backlight_service).